# idea `org.jetbrains.plugins.go` not found

Tags: intellij-idea, plugins, intellij-plugin, goland

I had this problem when I was developing the GoLand plug-in and install plugin from build jar `Plugin Gorm Generator depends on unknown plugin com.intellij.velocity`

```
<depends>org.jetbrains.plugins.go</depends>
```

build.gradle：

```
intellij {
    version '2020.2.1'
    sandboxDirectory = "${rootProject.rootDir}/idea-sandbox"
    type 'IU'
    plugins = ['java', 'DatabaseTools', 'Velocity']
    updateSinceUntilBuild false
    setPlugins("org.jetbrains.plugins.go:202.7319.5")
}
```

i'm not find

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the plugins list twice - by assigning an array to the `plugins` property and calling `setPlugins` method. That makes your first array simply overwritten by the Go dependency.

Try with the first approach only and simply append the Go entry at the end of your array.

Comment: Is it changed to the following

intellij {
    version '2020.2.1'
    sandboxDirectory = "${rootProject.rootDir}/idea-sandbox"
    type 'IU'
    plugins = ['java', 'DatabaseTools', 'Velocity','go']
}


console output:

> Cannot find builtin plugin go for IDE: C:\Users\admin\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.jetbrains.intellij.idea\ideaIU\2020.2.1\25c4dbe690c0ab8007abf2177fd8c31ee4405d9\ideaIU-2020.2.1

Comment: You can't use simply `go` for a Go plugin dependency in this case. As you've already created an issue in the [YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-250356) and received an answer for that dependency issue, please follow that thread.